# PerformSegue from long press on a a custom UiTableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

maybe the question has been asked several times, but can't find it.
I'm a newbie.

I have a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell.
in the cell there are 3 different labels.
I added the gesture recognizer on the custom cell, so that if long press is done on a label :
- label 1 should show another UiViewController
- label 2 should do a call
- label 3 should create a mail

for labels 2 and 3 i had no problem

but how to perform the segue to open the view controller ?

This is the storyboard

[image: Storyboard]

This is the custom tableviewcell

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class OfficeCell: UITableViewCell, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbOffice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbAddress: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbPhone: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbMail: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.setupLabelTap()
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func setupLabelTap() {

        let lbAddressTap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPressReconizer(_:)))
        self.lbAddress.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.lbAddress.addGestureRecognizer(lbAddressTap)

        let lbAddressTap2 = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPressReconizer(_:)))
        self.lbMail.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.lbMail.addGestureRecognizer(lbAddressTap2)

        let lbAddressTap3 = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPressReconizer(_:)))
        self.lbPhone.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.lbPhone.addGestureRecognizer(lbAddressTap3)
    }

    @objc func longPressReconizer(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("labelTapped")
        let etichetta :UILabel = sender.view as! UILabel
        print (etichetta.text!)
        switch etichetta.tag {
        case 0:

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveToMaps", sender: self)



        case 1:
            let telNumber = etichetta.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
            if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "telprompt://\(telNumber)") {
                let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
                if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
                    application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }
        case 2:

            if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
                let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
                mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
                mail.setToRecipients([etichetta.text!])
                mail.setSubject("Informazioni")

                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(mail, animated: true)
            } else {
                // show failure alert
            }

        default:
            print("default")
        }
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

but Xcode  give me this error

Value of type 'OfficeCell' has no member 'performSegue'

on 
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveToMaps", sender: self)

how to achieve what i need ?

Thanks in advance
Fabrizio

Comment: Please write down code of your TableView holding class you need to implement delegate and perform segue from main class because cell class can't perform segue ... i will guide you how to create protocol delegate to perform segue from main class after you post code of your main class where you create this cell

Comment: solved your issue sir ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement delegate and perform segue from main class because cell class can't perform segue ...  in `storyBoard` attach `"moveToMaps"`  segue from main controller

```
protocol CellDelegate {
  func didTapAddressButton()
}

class OfficeCell: UITableViewCell, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
var delegate: CellDelegate?
}
```

In your main View controller class

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OfficeCell", for: indexPath) as! OfficeCell
cell.delegate = self 
return cell 
}

extension MainController: CellDelegate {
   func didTapAddressButton(){
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveToMaps", sender: self)
    }
}
```